# Selecting nested Hibernate immutable objects throws org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Using:

- Hibernate 4.1.6
- Spring 4.1
- Java 8

I have two **immutable** data models:

**Parent model**

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name="PARENT_TABLE")
public class Parent {
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private final String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")
    @MapKey(name="key")
    Map<String, Child> children = new HashMap<>(1);

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public putChild(Child c) {
        Child childWithRef = new Child(this, c.getKey());
        children.put(c.getKey(), childWithRef);
    }
}
```

**Child model**

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name="CHILD_TABLE")
public class Child {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID") //say Parent has a generated ID
    private final Parent parent;

    @Column(name="KEY")
    private final String key;

    public Child(Parent p, String key) {
        this.parent = p;
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

And I want to fetch all the children, with their parents, so I try running (`entityManager` is from Spring):

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new Child(new Parent('sample name'), c.key) FROM Child c").getResultList()
```

But I get an exception (the problem indicated is with the *second* `new`):

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 1, column ...
```

**Does anyone know how to fetch nested immutable objects?**

I know Hibernate is really against immutability. Since I'm only performing simple database tasks, I'd like to try nonetheless.

Comment: you specify which columns you need, if you need them all you put "SELECT * FROM Child"

Comment: Sure [there is](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)...

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong, anyway [this](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2012/10/hql-and-new-keyword.html) suggests that you need to put the fully qualified name

Comment: Doesn't help :(
I now edited the question to show the problem indicated is with the _second_ `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is illegal for JPQL. The JPQL BNF (JPA 2.1 spec) states very clearly

```
select_expression ::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression | 
    identification_variable | OBJECT(identification_variable) | constructor_expression
constructor_expression ::= NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
constructor_item ::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression |
    identification_variable
```

You cannot nest constructor expressions.

Extract it out into a single object and then split into your structure in your code. For example

```
SELECT c.key FROM Child c
```

to get the "key" of the child, and then create the objects yourself in your code.

***EDIT FOR FULL CODE:***

Here is the full solution in case someone needs it too (there are probably many ways to improve and add performance, so use this as base for understanding):

```
//fetch all fields without instantiating any models from Hibernate;
//all aliases are for understanding only;
//notice `INNER JOIN c.parent` for fetching the parent data
List<Object[]> results = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p.id as parentId, p.name as parentName, p.key as parentKey, c.key as childKey FROM Child c INNER JOIN c.parent").getResultList()

//use map for parents identification
Map<Long, Parent> parentsMap = new HashMap<>(results.size())

//now use the data to instantiate the immutable models
results.forEach(resultRecord -> {
    Long parentId = (Long) resultRecord[0];
    if (parentsMap.get(parentId) == null) { //first time meeting this parent
        Parent p = new Parent(resultRecord[0], resultRecord[1], resultRecord[2]);
        parentsMap.put(parentId, p);
    }

    Child c = new Child(parentsMap.get(parentId), resultRecord[3]);
    parentsMap.get(parentId).putChild(c);
}
```

Comment: OK, but **I'm hoping to fetch the nested objects**, not to run the suggested query successfully...

Any suggestion to fetch them is welcome :)

Comment: good, it would be more complete answer if you told the OP what to do

Comment: @niceman I took that part as read; just select all you need and form the objects in your own code (there is no overhead with doing that). Now added.

Comment: @niel stockton, How can I extract the result into a single object?



The single object cannot be an instance of either of the immutable models I defined, because they have strict constructors (the ones displayed in the question).

Comment: create a temporary object and use constructor_expression for that, or just select all fields you need and get Object[] returned.